# Accidentally deleted Python3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python

I accidentally deleted python3 on Ubuntu from /usr/bin. Now every time i install python it gets installed in /usr/local/bin instead so i took python3.5 and placed it in /usr/bin and created a symlink for it from python3 as it was in the original. Somehow this doesn't work and I do not know what to do anymore.

```
     sudo apt-get install *anything* returns 

     dpkg : error processing package python3 (--configure)
            Errors encountered while processing 
            python3
            python3-distupgrade
            ubuntu-release-upgrade-core
            ubuntu-release-upgrade-gtk
```

As a result even terminal doesn't work so have to use xterm.

My /usr/bin looks as below - it looks good so I don't know what is wrong

```
         ls -l *python
```

in /usr/bin returns

```
         python -> python2.7
         python2 -> python2.7
         python2.7
         python3 
         python3 -> python3.5
         python3.5
```

and some symlinks to config files.

```
           dpkg -l
```

reveals Python in pFR state. Which I read as purge, failed, reinstall. Just not sure how to do this?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777987/python-3-5-broken-my-apt

Comment: How this is related with "linux-kernel"? If not, why do you use this tag? If your distro is Ubuntu, why "debian" tag?

Comment: sudo apt install -f gives same error. sudo apt install --reinstall python python-minimal looks for command-not-found within /usr/lib which is a python program so it crashes.